# Extract generic values from a known object

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm attempting to build a function that accepts two objects, one object I know the type of, the other will be generic. Is it possible to extract the generic properties from the known object?

I've kind of hit a wall on this one, but here's what I've tried:

```
interface IPerson {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  height: number;
  weight: number;
  job: string;
}

interface IAgeAndJob {
  age: number;
  job: string;
}

interface IHeightAndWeight {
  height: number;
  weight: string;
}

const person: IPerson = {
  name: 'Leon Kennedy',
  age: 21,
  height: 5.11,
  weight: 165,
  job: 'Police Officer'
};

const mapProperties = <IPerson, T>(person: IPerson): T => {

  let obj = {
    // extract properties from person where they exist
  } as T;
  console.log(obj);

  return obj;
};

const result = mapProperties<IPerson, IAgeAndJob>(person);
```

If I was doing this with a known type I would just grab the keys using `Object.keys` and iterate over the person object and grab what I need. Is there a way of doing this?

Comment: Not possible the way you've done it. Types don't exist at runtime so you can't reflect on them to pull out the keys of an interface. You could do it by adding another parameter with the keys you want and typing it `(keyof T)[]` and then grabbing those keys. Even that will be a hack though because the compiler cannot guarantee that the array of keys contains *all* the keys of T and that your return object is well-formed. I also don't think there's any way to ensure at compile-time that a given key is a valid index for both IPerson and T.

Comment: Incidentally the operation you are looking for is called [pick](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/lodash-_-pick-method/) and is implemented in various libraries like lodash and ramda.

Comment: Yeah I expected that was the case - thought I'd ask anyway as it'd be very convient to have something like this. Thanks anyway +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it in exactly the way you've shown. To see why, let's look at what it would be without any types:

```
const mapProperties = (person) => {
  let obj = {
    // extract properties from person where they exist
  };
  console.log(obj);

  return obj;
};
```

You see the problem: There's no runtime information about what properties you want to extract, so you can't write runtime code to extract them.

The closest you can come is a function where you tell it what properties you want:

```
const mapProperties = <ObjectType extends IPerson, Keys extends keyof IPerson>(
    person: ObjectType,
    keys: Keys[]
): Pick<ObjectType, Keys> => {
    const obj: Partial<ObjectType> = {};
    for (const key of keys) {
        obj[key] = person[key];
    }
    return obj as Pick<ObjectType, Keys>;
};

const result = mapProperties(person, ["age", "job"]);
console.log(result);
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIAVoGcD2JkDeAUMqciHALYQBcyWYUoA5gNwllzO3kCulAI2jsyyABYRgzMWDoh+QqCLIB3SdNl9BwjqQBWOAXQZMQbIgF8iRBHgbIADtjx0Mz-AF5Cu8lR4AiABkIPGQAaQgQEAgAEwBPfwAaHy4eACYARmTRCSkZOgBWADoMrJ81PM0MgDYC7LIDI2R-dBwAG2AkZAB5GBhO6CTLdhs7MGRKOAd0KBwnKDBgCCxkLwAeboE9CAQwABU4p2QIAA9IEBiVtyhcEETwiDiV0-PL5ABrR5wYNEwbvAAfAAKHzzW50TbbXYHJz1UifJ50CJPADaAF0iABKOjoTrvDZbHb7Q4Qe7IrAA1aU4iiWwgeyGPQ4uALYBwNoEqHEpyUrwECzKUgwHBQZBAun2BHIb4fR5YTHeUSiRkohFo1aOdyqx5owXIKyiKAQMC8KD4RnIOArXEIfGQokw0kPJ4A9gC6wS8ZGrC8NrjLyTaazeaLZZAsF4e4o-ypJLNRr+NGY9gS9oQIptHDMIHe31gZNAA)

I kept the object type generic because you'd used a generic type parameter, but if this is **only** for `IPerson`, you can remove `ObjectType` and just use `IPerson` directly:

```typescript
const mapProperties = <Keys extends keyof IPerson>(
    person: IPerson,
    keys: Keys[]
): Pick<IPerson, Keys> => {
    const obj: Partial<IPerson> = {};
    for (const key of keys) {
        obj[key] = person[key];
    }
    return obj as Pick<IPerson, Keys>;
};
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIAVoGcD2JkDeAUMqciHALYQBcyWYUoA5gNwllzO3kCulAI2jsyyABYRgzMWDoh+QqCLIB3SdNl9BwjqQBWOAXQZMQbIgF8iRBHgbIADtjx0Mz-AF5Cu8lR4AiABkIPGQAaQgQEAgAEwBPfwAaHy4eACYARmTRCSkZOgBWADoMrJ81PM0MgDYC7LIDI2R-dBwAG2AkZAB5GBhO6CTLdhs7MGRKOAd0KBwnKDBgCCxkLwAeCLiViAAPSBAYlYBrCDicGDRMKFwQAD4ACh95m9crm-rSE626TawAbQAukQAJR0dCdI5rNzXPCJcKnLC3VZI4iiWwgeyGPRguALYBwNpQt54JFeAgWZSkGA4KDIe7o+xfZDnZBfLDA7yiURYv5fAGrRzuXmnAGU5BWURQCBgXhQfBY5BwFbghCQ6HveFbW7sCnWBnjKVYXhtcZeSbTWbzRbLe7PWHIP7+VJJZqNfwA4HsBntCBFNo4Zj3Q3GsCeoA)

This begs the question: Where do we get the `["age", "job"]` array from?

You can't get it from `IAgeAndJob`, but you can flip that on its head and get `IAgeAndJob` and the array from a common source — a model object:

```typescript
const ageAndJobModel = {
    age: 42,
    job: "programmer",
};

type IAgeAndJob = typeof ageAndJobModel;
const ageAndJobKeys = Object.keys(ageAndJobModel) as (keyof IAgeAndJob)[];

// Using it elsewhere
const result = mapProperties(person, ageAndJobKeys);
console.log(result);
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIAVoGcD2JkDeAUMqciHALYQBcyWYUoA5gNwllzO3kCulAI2jsyyABYRgzMWDoh+QqCLIB3SdNl9BwjqQBWOAXQZMQbIgF8iRBHgbIADtjx0Mz-AF5Cu8lR4AiABkIPGQAaQgQEAgAEwBPfwAaHy4eACYARmTRCSkZOgBWADoMrJ81PM0MgDYC7LIDI2R-dBwAG2AkZAB5GBhO6CTLdhs7MGRKOAd0KBwnKDBgCCxkLwAeCLiViAAPSBAYlYBrCDicGDRMKFwQAD4ACh95m9crm-rSE626TawAbQAukQAJR0dCdI5rNzXPCJcKnLC3VZI4iiWwgeyGPRguALYBwNpQt54JFeAgWZSkGA4KDIe7o+xfZDnZBfLDA7yiURYv5fAGrRzuXmnAGU5BWURQCBgXhQfBY5BwFbghCQ6HveFbW7sCnWBnjVIAQQOAClDABZHAxCBtAWozjcOgAFjSH2QjTo-gcs2YUCo1CgQ11RDAcScaEN3GNMTNAgFoacLKNpotVpt7H1iqjKYEvwF3QEeggCDARTZ92TMdT1raHKVdK+LNQkYg0djwMBI0zUqwvDa4y8k2ms3mi2W92esKzrZzv2BGbs7QgRTaOGY9x7fbA86AA)

Comment: Thanks for the reply T.J. I wanted to avoid explicitly passing an array but this is as closes as we're going to get, at this point anyway. I've adapted it slightly for my specific needs. Thanks again +1